# Global shortcut to play/pause YouTube

Tags: shortcuts, browser, youtube

I would like to set a shortcut that will play/pause YouTube. I want it to work when I'm not focused on my browser or when I'm in a different tab.

If the command pauses any YouTube video running on any of the opened tabs, that would be OK. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Firefox 39.0.3.

I know that I can use VLC to watch the video and use its global shortcuts but I would like a solution that works with the browser.

Comment: on youtube pressing button 'k' while watching the video, make it pause/play

Comment: @SijinKrishnan Thanks but that only works when you are in the video tab.

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/538168/can-i-pause-youtube-in-chrome-from-the-command-line

Comment: Definitely try the [answer at the other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/581610/101830), it's not perfect but it gets you somewhere. One thing that no solution seems to get right is what to do when several youtube tabs are open. It's not a trivial problem. That answer will toggle the active tab in the youtube window (even if that is a background window).

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of browser extensions that allow you to control YouTube videos without having to switch to the tab, such as this
[Multi-tab Controller for YouTube](https://andrew-flower.com/projects/MTC) which is an extension/add-on for Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

rewolf's answer didn't work out for me. [Multi-tab Controller for YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-tab-controller-for/jmhlhicfnbopnflmpgdbeicgooafepli) doesn't allow you to set shortcuts for media control buttons, so you'll have to use your mouse every time.

Here is how I solved it:

1. Install [streamkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen?hl=en) extension
2. Go to chrome://extensions/shortcuts
3. Find that extension
4. Set a shortcut. For example, ctrl+space