# YouTube pausing script works from command line, but not from shortcut

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, shortcut-keys, google-chrome

I wanted to pause YouTube and tried the last approach [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538168/can-i-pause-youtube-in-chrome-from-the-command-line) using `kill -SIGSTOP [pid].` Now the script works fine in the terminal but it doesn't work when invoked using a keyboard shortcut. The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /tmp/TimChromepid.RUN ]; then
  mv /tmp/TimChromepid.RUN /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD
  NMR=$(< /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD) 
  kill -SIGSTOP < /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD
else
  NMR=$(< /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD) 
  mv /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD /tmp/TimChromepid.RUN
  kill -SIGCONT $NMR
fi
```

I used the variable *'NMR'* to store the *PID*, for when I feed it directly into `kill` I get this error:

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

As far as I can test it seems that it can run the script, and the `if`-statement, but it can't read the number from file nor can it execute  `kill`.

How can I fix this and what's going on?

Comment: Your `kill -SIGSTOP < /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD` suggests that `kill` reads a PID from stdin — which it doesn't, thus the usage message. Try `kill -SIGSTOP $(cat /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD)` instead.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Yes, that did it, thank you! :)

Comment: Did you fix the shebang? Please [edit] your question and change the code accordingly. To read the PID from the file you can do `kill -SIGSPEC $(</tmp/TimChromepid.PSD)` or use `cat` as shown by @PerlDuck. Please add some `echo` lines to test and redirect the whole output to a log file, especially that of `kill` with `&>/path/to/logfile`, then provide the content of the log file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem has something to do with whether the script is run via keyboard shortcut or directly in a terminal. It's rather an error in your `if` branch and the script will alternately work and fail.

In the `if` branch you wrote

```
kill -SIGSTOP < /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD
```

which means: *pipe the content of file `/tmp/TimChromepid.PSD` into `kill`'s stdin*. But `kill` doesn't read anything from *stdin*, it just accepts the PID as a command line parameter, which wasn't given. That's why it told you about its usage.

To fix it, simply do as you did in the `else` branch, i.e. either replace `kill -SIGSTOP < /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD` with `kill -SIGSTOP $(< /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD)` or use `$NMR`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /tmp/TimChromepid.RUN ]; then
    mv /tmp/TimChromepid.RUN /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD
    NMR=$(< /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD) 
    kill -SIGSTOP $NMR
else
    NMR=$(< /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD) 
    mv /tmp/TimChromepid.PSD /tmp/TimChromepid.RUN
    kill -SIGCONT $NMR
fi
```